# Title tag and url for paging, which is good?

Tags: title, seo

I have a page which has 3 pages
First page;
Url: ex.com/my-good-page
Title tag: My Good Page

Second page
Option 1:
url: ex.com/my-good-page/2
Title tag: My Good Page - 2 => Added page number

Option 2:
url: ex.com/my-good-page?page=2
Title tag: My Good Page => No change

I don't know which one to choose between option 1 and 2.
Title tag should be unique. Is it still good for paging? So I should choose option 1?

Could you give me advise?

---

I thought option 1 was good.
But, I want google search give the first page result on top not the page 2~..
And I found popular sites are using option 2. This confused me.

SEOChat.com uses option 2 approach. ?pp=12 with the same title tag.

Stackoverflow, which got popular rapidly, also use ?page=2&sort=name approach.

I heard Option 1 was good, but I found popular sites use option 2!

Any opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I would use...

http://example.com/my-good-page-2
http://example.com/my-good-page/2

Comment: Ok, and what happen if you got an article"how Montreal Canadien lost a game 5-2"? "how-Montreal-canadiens-lost-a-game-5-2-2" You lost the "easy reading" point on that one ;)

Comment: I personally use /id/seo-title/pid, but I do agree with you, almost :)

http://pokit.etf.ba/upload/pokitcadee88ca0c7c9650dc4380fd51a742a.png

Comment: You personnaly use "id/seo-title/pid", but you said "I would use "/my-good-page-2" hehe

Comment: StackOverflow uses ?page=2 approach and they got ranked high.
Is it stratege that they want to emphasise on the first page so that link juice doesn't split?

Comment: @Dominique, I always use IDs, so I had to adapt :P

Sky Kim
Yes, we use same approach here... http://emag.ba/forum/tema/117/emag-novi-server?page=2 ... but, on other site i use /seo-title/id/pageid, and everything is well indexed
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Afotozunic.com%2Ffoto-aparati%2F3

Maybe it is just a preference (between these cases, since they are all optimized)

Comment: what about title tag? I was confused with "Title tag should be unique for good seo". Is it valid stmt for paging? page 1 through page 100 has all same title, is it OK?

Comment: Yes if it's a forum thread for example, but if you are listing categories like Cameras, Cameras - Page 2, you can then add page titles with numbers. I add them in second case because of previous bad experience, when Google, decided to remove all subversion and instead of starting 3600 links it came down to 600, because pages were too similar, although there is different data.
I avoid directory type links deeper than level 3, because of this.

IMHO you should make every page different as can be.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I would chose the first option, I think it allow to "split" the content better. It is easier to read site/article/page than site/article?page=number, also the htacess rule will be easier with site/article/page.

My last point is that choosing to use site/article syntax is to go away from the old GET syntax (for many reasons, seo, aestetic, etc), so by puttin ?page=1 it looks like you don't know what you want.